# Use the Enter key to open a link

Tags: jquery, html

This is all I have so far but cant figure out the Enter part. I write it to open the "input onclick" part. I have tried using For days to get it to work. It works just fine on the website www.unblockmysites.weebly.com but would like the Surf key to open without having to click it. Thanks for any reply. 1st post.

```
 <input id="input" class="css-input" name="url" onfocus="this.value='';" style="border: 1px solid #A4A4A4; font-size: 0.9em; padding: 10px; width: 450px;" type="text" value="Type url here.." >

 <input onclick="window.open('http://webmoha200.appspot.com/' + 

 window.document.getElementById('input').value.replace(/^https?:\/\//,''))" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em; margin: 2px 0; padding: 1px; width: 100px;" type="button" class="css-input" value="Surf">
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The most probably thing that happens here is that post will be deleted or massive downvoted. Please, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then make a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution based on javascript:

```
<input id="input" class="css-input" name="url" onfocus="this.value='';" style="border: 1px solid #A4A4A4; font-size: 0.9em; padding: 10px; width: 450px;" type="text" value="Type url here.." onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);">
```

javascript:

```
function searchKeyPress(e)
{

e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == 13)

   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="input" class="css-input" name="url" style="border: 1px solid #A4A4A4; font-size: 0.9em; padding: 10px; width: 450px;" type="text" value="Type url here." />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#input').on('keydown', function(e){
         if(e.which === 13){
             window.location = $(this).val();
         }
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Adrian, but I think you missed the "window.open" code that opens that link. You may have done it and changed the code but its not working on my end

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```js
$('#input').on('keydown', function(e){

     if(e.which === 13) //enter
         //do something
});
```

```html
 <input id="input" class="css-input" name="url" onfocus="this.value='';" style="border: 1px solid #A4A4A4; font-size: 0.9em; padding: 10px; width: 450px;" type="text" value="Type url here.." >
```